Regarding the application process for PhDs to universities in Norway, Switzerland and Ireland?
I will be completing my master’s degree in international trade this year (I’m currently studying in a developing country). For my PhD, I’m planning to apply to universities in Norway, Ireland, Switzerland.. next year, as I’ve heard that PhD students in these countries receive a salary similar to a regular job.
I was wondering if anyone has experience with the application process in these countries. How competitive is it to get accepted into a PhD program? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated, especially since I haven’t decided on a specific thesis topic yet.

Actually, answers for the three named counties are missing at the canonical question, but should be provided there, not here.

I don't understand why the question was closed, in this case people who have prior experience won't see my question and I won't be able to get the answers I need. If the countries are missing at the canonical question. It's one more reason to NOT close this question. Honestly, you need to revise this policy

If the answers for those countries are provided in the canonical question it will benefit everyone, including yourself. There is no reason to fragment the answers. Watch for changes there. And if anyone has knowledge about how the process works there, or in other countries not yet included, I encourage you to add an answer there, keeping the same general format as the other answers.

Let me note, however, that if funding is your main concern, that many countries other than these three provide funding for doctoral students. Germany is similar to what you describe (similar to salary). The US funds through teaching assistantships. So, don't restrict to these three for just funding concerns alone.

@Lucylucy Actually, that's why we "close" questions, rather than delete them. Now, if someone is watching for questions about Norway, they'll see your question, and then be appropriately directed to the canonical Q. Now, you won't be notified, but it would be polite for such an answerer to maybe let you know here.

I think we would be far more likely to get an answer for the canonical question if we left this open until there was an answer. We can always copy the answer to the canonical question later, if we get one. (That said, three countries is too many, recommend having one country per post).
